# Combining denoise node with other nodes in compositor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, noise-reduction, denoise

I'm rendering a thing in cycles and I think I put the Intel denoise node in the wrong spot, because it won't mix with the rest of my nodes in the composite. I've been using Blender for a couple of weeks so I'm pretty new, and also my brain just...has trouble wrapping itself around nodes. What do I need to change about this node set-up so that the denoising node works with the other ones? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Render Layers' Image output, use the output of Denoise Image in the add node. Remember, the denoised output substitutes for the standard render layer output.[image: new node setup]